# How to use a cell's text in a formula?

Tags: excel

My Excel file has eight different worksheets. Seven of them are named to the days of the week ("Monday", "Tuesday", etc.). The last worksheet, called "Week" should provide some general data, based on these days.

In the first column of "Week", I typed the days of the week, so `A1: Monday`, `A2: Tuesday`, etc. In the second column, I'd now like to add a formula that uses data from the worksheet of the corresponding day. For example: `B1: =SUMIF(Monday!C1:C4;mycondition;Monday!D1:D4)`, `B2: =SUMIF(Tuesday!C1:C4;mycondition;Tuesday!D1:D4)`, etc. This works fine, but I don't want to type the days of the week all over again.

Is it possible to use the text of the cells A1-A7 in "Week" in these formulas? I tried `=SUMIF(A1!A1:A4;mycondition;A1!B1:B4)`, but that didn't work.

---

**Note:** If I should add a new row to one of the "day" worksheets, the cell references in the formula in "Week" should be changed too. `=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A1&"!C1:C4");mycondition;INDIRECT(A1&"!D1:D4"))` isn't what I'm looking for, because it fixes `C1:C4` and `D1:D4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT` function:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A1&"!$C:$C");mycondition;INDIRECT(A1&"!$D:$D"))
```

(I'm not sure if the syntax is correct (,/;), I dont't have an English Excel version.)

Comment: It turns out that your suggestion isn't exactly what I'm looking for after all. I've added a note to my question to explain what goes wrong.

Comment: You've got any possibility to construct the string in `INDIRECT` as you need it. As I don't know, how to find out the range you want to use, I changed the code that the whole columns are included in the calculation. You can also use named ranges or anything else.